# Law of large numbers: average value of a function approaching the expected value when the domain is sampled according to a different distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, law-of-large-numbers

Let $x_1$, $x_2$, ... , $x_n$ be sampled according to some distribution $f$.

Will the law of large numbers hold for some function $g(x)$ where

$$\frac{g(x_1) + g(x_2) + \cdots + g(x_n)}{n} \longrightarrow E[g(x)]\ ?$$

If so how? Will this work for all sampling distributions $f$?

Comment: Let $Y_1 = g(X_1)$, $Y_2 = g(X_2)$, and so on. Check if $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ satisfy the conditions for the law of large numbers.

Comment: @angryavian yes they do if they are i.i.d.

Comment: Does that answer your question then?